What is the equivalent function to `ParseObject#createWithoutData` in Flutter?
What is the equivalent function to ParseObject#createWithoutData(Class<T>, String) in Flutter?
I couldn't find one.

Possibly: final foo = ParseObject('subclass')..objectId='someObjId';
